# How can I print taxonomy id of a blog category field in a node

Tags: theming, taxonomy-terms, nodes

Please, how can I print the taxonomy id of a blog category field in the node template?
Using {{ content.field_category }} prints the term name but how can I get the unique term id instead?﻿